# Clevo NS50AU suspend mode issue with keyboard and power led

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, suspend, power-management

I've just acquired a Clevo NS50AU with "i7-1360P" cpu powered by Ubuntu 22.04 and kernel 5.15

When in suspend mode :

- The keyboard remains illuminated
- The power led does not blink

I've searched on the Net but cannot found a solution, neither same question :-(

Thanks for diagnostic idea. Cheers.

[UPDATE 2023-12-03]

I've changed the suspend mode "s2idle" to "deep" with

```
echo deep | sudo tee /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

Now the keyboard light is off and the power led is blinking ... But after some seconds the laptop is powering off ... After switching on it reboots.

Comment: I've try with an **Ubuntu 23.10** (Live USB) and it's the **same problem**, like if only the screen goes black and computer is not in suspend mode :-(

Comment: I'm running **LinuxMint 21.2** Cinnamon (Kernel 6.2.1) with **same problem**.

Comment: Trying Kernel 6.2.16 with same problem

Comment: I don't know what equipment stays powered up, but the computer on "suspend" in a bag is **hot enough to be worrying** (dangerous ?).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I contacted Clevo and I asked them:

> I have a Clevo NS50AU with Ubuntu, but when I close the lid and the laptop is set to Hibernation, the keyboard lights do not turn off. The Keyboard shortcuts also do not function, so that the keyboard lights are always on.
> It is the same result with Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04
> Is there a fix for this? Or could you please guide me to a place where I might find a solution for this?
> Thanks :)

Got an answer from marketing@clevo.com.tw:

> The Ubuntu's S3 settings are different, when comparing to Windows based OS.  Unfortunately we don't have the expertise to come up with a workaround.
>
> Our partner System76 is able to offer solution on some of our models, so our recommendation is to contact them regarding Linux based model purchases in the future.
>
> Thank you for your understanding,

Comment: Thanks. But it seems System76 is doing stuff for "pop os" not for "unbuntu" :-(